# Не отрабатывает скрипт, показывающий блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код, который должен показывать соседний блок, который следует за ним, но он не показывает.

```js
$(".b-menu-catalog__item--parent").click(function(){
  var h = $(this + ".b-menu-catalog__sub:visible");
  if (h.length>0){
    $(h).css("display","none");
  }else{
    $(this).children(this + ".b-menu-catalog__sub").css("display","block");
  }
});
```

```css
.b-menu-catalog__sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-menu-catalog b-menu-catalog--open">
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--orange b-menu-catalog__item--parent">
    <span>Каталог</span>
  </div>
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__sub">
    <a href="http://localhost/school/index.php?page=razdel&amp;sel_node=169125" class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--sub">Методическая литература</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще можно так сделать:

```js
 $(".b-menu-catalog__item--parent").click(function(){
  var sel = $(this).next();
  $(sel).toggle();
});
```

```css
.b-menu-catalog__sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-menu-catalog b-menu-catalog--open">
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--orange b-menu-catalog__item--parent">
<span>Каталог</span>
  </div>
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__sub">
<a href="http://localhost/school/index.php?page=razdel&amp;sel_node=169125" class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--sub">Методическая литература</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот за это спасибо! )

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).children(".b-menu-catalog__sub").css("display","block");` у вас `this` это не родитель для `b-menu-catalog__sub`

```js
$(".b-menu-catalog__item--parent").click(function(){


  var selectParent = $(this).parents()[0];  // берем родителя 

  
  var h = $(this).find(".b-menu-catalog__item--parent + .b-menu-catalog__sub:visible");
      if (h.length>0){
        $(h).css("display","none");
      }else{


        $(selectParent).children(".b-menu-catalog__sub").css("display","block"); // показываем дочерний элемент


      }
    });
```

```css
.b-menu-catalog__sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-menu-catalog b-menu-catalog--open">
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--orange b-menu-catalog__item--parent">
    <span>Каталог</span>
  </div>
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__sub">
    <a href="http://localhost/school/index.php?page=razdel&amp;sel_node=169125" class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--sub">Методическая литература</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так в итоге сделал:

```js
  $(".b-menu-catalog__item--parent").click(function(){
  var sel = $(this).next();

  var h = $(sel).css("display")
  if (h=="block"){
    $(sel).css("display","none");
  } else{
    $(sel).css("display","block");
  }
});
```

```css
.b-menu-catalog__sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-menu-catalog b-menu-catalog--open">
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--orange b-menu-catalog__item--parent">
<span>Каталог</span>
  </div>
  <div class="b-menu-catalog__sub">
<a href="http://localhost/school/index.php?page=razdel&amp;sel_node=169125" class="b-menu-catalog__item b-menu-catalog__item--sub">Методическая литература</a>
  </div>
</div>
```